# Need to display the max price and company that has it

Tags: python, pandas

So, i just started working with python and i need to display the maximum price and the company that has it. I got the data from an CSV file that has multiple columns that describes some cars. I'm only interested in two of them: price and company.

I need to display the maximum price and the company that has it. Some advice? 
This is what i tried and I don't know how to get the company too, not only the maximum price.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Automobile_data.csv")
for x in df['price']:
    if x == df['price'].max():
       print(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how not to use Pandas. Pandas is made to avoid loops

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Automobile_data.csv")

max_price = df[df['price'] == df['price'].max()]
print(max_price)
```

That is how you would do it. If you only want price and company

```
print(max_price[['company','price']])
```

Explanation: we create a boolean filter that true if the price is equal to maximum price. We use this as a mask to catch what we need.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I didn't knew that about Pandas. The problem was about getting the company name, i couldn't find a solution until jezrael's answer

Comment: Just like viewing only price, just add whatever you need as a list. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @AndreiGH if you know the row index number of the max_price, you can get the company by using e.g. df.at[3,'company_name'] (index, column_name). If you don't know the index, you can get it using .idxmax(). Just an addendum for future reference. Btw, you can accept Prayson's answer by hovering to the left of the answer and clicking on the tick that appears. You both gain rep! :)

Comment: I am not sure one needs index. Simple filter works. You could just do everything in one line of code: `print(df[df['price'] == df['price].max()][['company','price']])`

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel - No, rather not... Here is better loc - check edit in my answer...

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel - Why not? Because better is filtering in loc - by max and also by columns names. If use `print(df[df['price'] == df['price].max()][['company','price']])` then filter all rows and then columns. A bit overcomplicated in my opinion.

Comment: I believe it depends on background and readability. I come from SQL background where I state SELECT company, price FROM df QUALIFY MAX(price) OVER()()== price.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel - ya, in pandas it is different. Maybe in future you write it different...

Comment: Totally true, but readability is important in my field as it is easy for future handover. Your solution is brilliant but it involves advance Pandas features. This is purely my opinion:) You know 10K better than I do.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html), create index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and get `company` name by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'company':list('abcdef'),
         'price':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

print (df)
  company  price
0       a      7
1       b      8
2       c      9
3       d      4
4       e      2
5       f      3

print(df['price'].max())
9
print(df.set_index('company')['price'].idxmax())
c
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
s = df.set_index('company')['price'].agg(['max','idxmax'])
print (s['max'])
9
print (s['idxmax'])
c
```

If possible duplicated maximum values and need all companies of max price use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - get `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'company':list('abcdef'),
         'price':[7,8,9,4,2,9],

})

print (df)
  company  price
0       a      7
1       b      8
2       c      9
3       d      4
4       e      2
5       f      9

print(df['price'].max())
9

#only first value
print(df.set_index('company')['price'].idxmax())
c

#all maximum values
s = df.loc[df['price'] == df['price'].max(), 'company']
print (s)
2    c
5    f
Name: company, dtype: object
```

If need one row DataFrame:

```
out = df.loc[df['price'] == df['price'].max(), ['company','price']]
print (out)
  company  price
2       c      9


out = df.loc[df['price'] == df['price'].max(), ['company','price']]
print (out)
  company  price
2       c      9
5       f      9
```

Comment: This is awesome. I should use more of these functions:) +1

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the complete answer of Jezrael, I would suggest using `groupby` as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'company':list('abcdef'),
         'price':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

sorted_df = df.groupby(['price']).max().reset_index()

desired_row = sorted_df.loc[sorted_df.index[-1]]

price = desired_row[0]
company = desired_row[1]

print('Maximum price is: ', price)
print('The company is: ', company)
```

The above code prints:

```
Maximum price is:  9
The company is:  c
```